# Unsure how to reset stream based on previous values

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm working on the following RxJs stream within an Angular app and I'm running into trouble resetting the values. I have multiple places in my application which emit values to these three observables within the `combineLatest` call here, such as when a user changes a filter setting, or updates the page via an input field. Additionally I have a lazy load function that ticks the page forward when the user gets near the bottom.

When `name` and `filter` update I want it to only return the most recent data from `getContent`, but when the `page` observable has a new value I want it to combine the previous data with the current one via the `scan` operator. The only problem I have is that I can't seem to figure out the best way to do this within scan because at that point it doesn't know what the current and previous values were within `mergeMap` from `name` and `filter`.

```
getContent(name, page filter) {
    return this.http
      .get(
        `${this.API_BASE}/${name}/${filter}/${page}`
)
```

The stream looks like the following:

```
this.results$ = combineLatest(
  this.dataService.getName(),
  this.dataService.getPage(),
  this.dataService.getFilter()
).pipe(
  mergeMap(([name, page, filter]) => {
     this.dataService.getContent(name, filter, page);
  }),
  scan(
    (
      acc,
      curr
    ) => {
      this.nextPage = curr[curr.length - 1].id;
      if (acc.length && curr.length) {
         return acc.concat(curr);
      }

      return acc;
    },
    []
  )
);
```

The template is just a div that gets looped over and updated with the `async` pipe, which I'd like to keep if possible. Is there a better way to handle this within a single stream, or a way to break this apart in a way where I can get it to do what I need it to?

Comment: It is not clear to me which `type` should be notified by the stream you are building. Out of the `scan` operator it seems you are getting a stream that notifies an array of objects of the type returned by `this.dataService.getContent`, on the other hand you say that if either `name` or `filter` emit, you want just to pass the result of `this.dataService.getContent`, so not an array but a single object of that type. Can you clarify better?

Comment: In all cases I want `Record<string, string>[]` to come back, I just don't want the combined `acc + curr` value when certain things emit, ie `name` or `filter`, but I do when `page` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `combineLatest` on your "criteria", then feed that to a `switchMap` (*provides reset whenever criteria changes*), then feed the criteria result to the observable of the `getPage()`.  At that point, you have all 3 arguments needed to call `getContent()`.

Something like this should work for you:

```js
  results$ = combineLatest([
    this.dataService.getName(),
    this.dataService.getFilter(),
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(([name, filter]) => this.dataService.getPage().pipe(
      startWith(undefined), // initially emit `undefined` becuase there's not a "next page" cursor for the first call.
      mergeMap(page => this.dataService.getContent(name, filter, page)),
      scan((acc, curr) => {
        this.nextPage = curr[curr.length - 1].id;
  
        if (curr.length) {
          return acc.concat(curr);
        }
  
        return acc;
      }, [])
    )),
  );
```

---

It's best if the observable stream doesn't rely on outside variables. (`this.nextPage`)

We can get around this by changing the shape we emit.  Instead of emitting only the "results" we can also have it include the "nextPage" information as well:

```js
  query$ = combineLatest([
    this.dataService.getName(),
    this.dataService.getFilter(),
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(([name, filter]) => this.dataService.getPage().pipe(
      startWith(undefined),
      mergeMap(page => this.dataService.getContent(name, filter, page)),
      scan(
        (acc, curr) => ({ 
          results  : curr.length ? acc.results.concat(curr) : acc.results, 
          nextPage : curr[curr.length - 1]?.id
        }),
        { results: [] as Result[], nextPage: undefined })
    )),
  );
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="query$ | async as query">

  <div *ngFor="let result of query.results">
    {{ result.label }}
  </div>

  <button *ngIf="query.nextPage" (click)="loadMore(query.nextPage)"> 
    Load More 
  </button>

</ng-container>
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75233661-solution?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

---

Two last notes:

1. If the `getPage()`, `getFilter()`, & `getName()` methods don't take any params, you can simply declare them as observables, rather than methods that return observables: `page$`, `filter$`, `name$`
2. The data service is exposing multiple observables, so the component can subscribe to them and feed the emissions back to the service's own `getContent()` method. Since your data service maintains all of the observable sources, it would probably be simpler to declare the content as an observable in the service instead of in the component.

Check out [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75233661-solution-b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts) if you want to :-)